# Showing Custom Menus in the sidebar

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages

I want to get custom menu in my top level page and the sub pages which are not child of the top level pages.

I got many examples using wp_list_pages but it requires the sub pages should be the child of the top level page.

How do use the wp_get_nav_menu_items function to show the custom menu in child page and the toplevel page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the widget "custom menu" in the widgets. Create a custom menu with the pages you need and give that menu to this widget.

Comment: Hi MidunN,How to do this without the plugin. Thanks

Comment: Its not a plugin..This widget will be defult with your theme. You dont need to install another plugin for this.